# Timer across the multiple activities

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have an android app with several activities. I need to start a timer when the first activity starts and end the timer when the last activity starts and show the elapsed time. How can i use Asynctask to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `Application`, declare a `public static long started;` which will be assigned to `System.currentTimeMillis();` by the first Activity in `onCreate()` or `onResume()`. Have the last `Activity` read the value and calculate delta.
If you absolutely want to use `AsyncTask` (which I think is irrelevant in this case), you'll at least need a mediatory `Service` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Make it static.
Why you use timer to count time? Will be better to use currentTimeMillis ().